# How to disallow TRACE http method in spring boot actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, http-method

I have a server  on port = 8078 and spring boot actuator on port = 8081.I want to disable TRACE Http method on both. I already create customizer bean(see below). But with this bean I disallowed only Trace on 8078. It's looks like actuator doesn't see this bean. How to disable TRACE http method on management server?

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class CustomUndertowCustomizer {
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> undertowCustomizer() {
        return (factory) ->
                factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo ->
                        deploymentInfo.addInitialHandlerChainWrapper(handler -> {
                            HttpString[] disallowedHttpMethods = {HttpString.tryFromString("TRACE"),
                                    HttpString.tryFromString("TRACK")};
                            return new DisallowedMethodsHandler(handler, disallowedHttpMethods);
                        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
           
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;     
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter; 
           
@Component
public class Filter extends OncePerRequestFilter { 
           
    @Override 
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
    { 
        try {
            if (req.getMethod().equals("TRACE")) {
                res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            } else { 
                filterChain.doFilter(req, res); 
            }
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is still work for 8078, but management on 8081 doesn't see it=(

Comment: The filter isn’t even called for TRACE requests.